# 2 base items change the items in a form

Tags: custom-list, validation

Not really sure how to go about this, I want this vanilla sharepoint if possible.

I have two 'Base Items' Player and Manager. These both have different forms. Some columns will be the same but some will be different depending on the base item selected. I want this in the same list so if I choose to create a view, I can see both Player and Manager in the same view. None of the columns are required.
Can this be done in say Column Validation. Hiding and showing particular sections depending on the Base Item
I'll say it again, I would rather this be vanilla sharepoint and kept as simple as possible instead of adding JS files etc to the list/form

Answer (score 0):

You can use Content Types in this case, make two Content Types.. One as Player and other as Manager.. The common columns will exist in both Content Types and the unique ones will exist in respective..

Each Content Type has its own Display, New and Edit forms so you don't have to worry about forms here..

Also you can see all of them in a single list as single view.. Just add the Content Type column as well in the view so you can identify the difference..

Go to List Settings -> Advance Settings -> Allow management of Content Types..

Now go to List Settings -> Under Content Types you will see default `Item` content type, and option to add more content types..